# multiplying numbers within a conditional

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I need to fill in the circles conditional on being above the line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
        \draw (0,\a)--(13,\a);
    }
    \foreach \a in {0,...,13}{
        \draw (\a,0)--(\a,5);
    }

    \foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
        \foreach \b in {0,...,13}{
            \ifnum \a > \b 
            % \ifnum 13*\a > 5*\b  
            \draw[fill=black] (\b,\a) circle (0.1); \else 
            \draw[] (\b,\a) circle (0.1); \fi
      }
    }

    \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image]

Conditionals in Tikz are not-so-easy and you can't define numbers to be just numbers and the operations require special care.

e.g. [Tikz/Pgf if statements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4628/tikz-pgf-if-statements)

Comment: What should happen to those circles which are not entirely above the line but on it?

Comment: @Skillmon possibly nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ/`pgf` also support calculations, e.g. via `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line cap=rect]
        \foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
            (0,\a)--(13,\a)
        }
        \foreach \a in {0,...,13}{
            (\a,0)--(\a,5)
        }
    ;

    \foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
        \draw (0,\a)--(13,\a);
    }
    \foreach \a in {0,...,13}{
        \draw (\a,0)--(\a,5);
    }

    \foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
        \foreach \b in {0,...,13}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\q{5*\b/13}
            \ifdim\q pt<\a pt
                \draw[fill=black] (\b,\a) circle (0.1);
            \else
                \draw[] (\b,\a) circle (0.1);
            \fi
        }
    }

    \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Variant with a calculation via e-TeX and without division to avoid rounding issues.

```
\foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
    \foreach \b in {0,...,13}{
        \ifnum\numexpr 5 * \b\relax < \numexpr \a * 13\relax
            \draw[fill=black] (\b,\a) circle (0.1);
        \else
            \draw[] (\b,\a) circle (0.1);
        \fi
    }
}
```

The option `line cap=rect` improves, how the outer horizontal and vertical lines meet in the corners.

Comment: Seems like I was too slow...

Answer (score 2):

Using `\pgfmathparse`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
        \draw (0,\a)--(13,\a);
    }
    \foreach \a in {0,...,13}{
        \draw (\a,0)--(\a,5);
    }

    \foreach \a in {0,...,5}{
        \foreach \b in {0,...,13}{
            \pgfmathparse{13/5*\a}
            \ifdim \pgfmathresult pt > \b pt
            % \ifnum 13*\a > 5*\b  
            \draw[fill=black] (\b,\a) circle (0.1); \else 
            \draw[] (\b,\a) circle (0.1); \fi
      }
    }

    \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]